# Using setprop to get DNS server details in Android Ethernet Connection

Tags: android, ethernet

To provide ethernet connectivity in my Android(Kitkat) development board,I used ndc command tool to set the DNS server IPs. Everything works right but am not able to view the DNS server details using getprop from the system properties. I used the following commands in the android shell,

```
ndc resolver flushif eth0
ndc resolver flushdefaultif
ndc resolver setifdns eth0 x.x.x.x x.x.x.x
ndc resolver setdefaultif eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say but it just does not seem possible. Certainly not via `getprop` as system properties aren't used any more (as you've discovered).

As far as I can see, `ndc` just passes the values to libc which just holds them in memory. Nothing I can find actually queries them for display though.